# QGIS 1.8 in Linuxmint 14 (Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, linux

I have Linux Mint 14 KDE which is based on Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal.
In the QGIS download page, there's no "Quantal" repositiries. I'm trying to use the "Precise" repositories, but I'm not allowed to install the latest QGIS version (1.8) and I received many messages of broken packages.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Lucas

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ppa/+packages

Answer (score 2):

Renew repository and update packages qgis

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable  
$ sudo apt-get update  
$ sudo apt-get install qgis
```

If you have broken dependencies for qgis.

```
$ sudo apt-get clean
```

or
    $ sudo apt-get autoclean

And then, ask apt to try and correct any broken dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

If the output is similar to :

```
$ 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

it means that you need some extra packages that you weren't informed about. To install them run:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Bravo Martn, it works on my Ubuntu 13.04 x64